# Tablesorting with comma seperator not working

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

I am trying to sort the data in the table using tablesorting plugin but the data has commas(,) as the separator so it is not sorting properly. I think it is considering the number as a string. With the help of google, I have found some codes but those are not working for me. Here is what I have tried so far.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.tablesorter.addParser({
      id: "fancyNumber",
      is: function(s) {
        return /^[0-9]?[0-9,\.]*$/.test(s);
      },
      format: function(s) {
        return jQuery.tablesorter.formatFloat( s.replace(/,/g,'') );
      },
      type: "numeric"
    });
    $("#myTable").tablesorter({
        widgets  : ['zebra']
    });     
});
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

I have given class `<th width="62" class="{sorter: 'fancyNumber'}">column</th>` to the column also.

Comment: Edited the question. Hope this can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the sorter in the class name like this:

```
<th width="62" class="{sorter: 'fancyNumber'}">column</th>
```

Make sure you are also loading in the [metadata addon](https://github.com/jquery-archive/jquery-metadata) because that is needed to process that format.

Or, if you don't want to use that plugin, you can set the parser using the `headers` option:

```
$(function(){
  $('table').tablesorter({
    headers : {
      0 : { sorter: 'fancyNumber' }
    }
  });
});
```